# Wondering what these multi-colored extra pages are?

Tags: plugins, menus, pages

[image]

I've recently taken over managing the Wordpress site for my non-profit. The person who set it up before me has a lot of plug-ins installed and widgets set up. Additionally, there are these 5 multi-colored "pages" that are outside of the normal Pages area. It's very confusing because half the website pages are under 'Pages' and the other half are under one of these tabs.

Just trying to figure out where these tabs are coming from - is this a plug in of some sort? I tried going through the plug ins to see what could be doing this, but there are so many it's hard to weed through them all.

Any help would be great!!

Comment: Looks like [Custom Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types), added by the theme or a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

These are almost certainly [custom post types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types).  In the definition of the custom post type, it is possible to define a menu_icon which can be a file or an icon from the iconfont. It is this menu_icon that is showing up in your admin menu.

I also notice "Programs Categories" in your menu,  this looks like a [custom options page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) - which will have also been defined in a plugin or theme.